# Is there any default timestamp that gets updated when a document gets added/updated to the search index?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I know there is a _ts (Timestamp) property in Azure Cosmos Db that gets updated on any document insert/update.

Is there anything similar for documents in Azure Search Index?

(or)

Should we do have our own timestamp property?

Answer (score 5):

In Azure Search index you get only the fields you put in. So no, there is no timestamp on the document (at least nothing is exposed via the API).

One of the supported field types is Edm.DateTimeOffset - you can use it to maintain such field if you have to.

Comment: Thanks for being an Azure Search user Georgi and helping others with your expertise!